# Do new Windows firewall rules affect currently open connections?

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

If I added a rule to windows firewall that blocked an ip or port currently used by an open connection, does that rule take effect immediately or only after the connection were closed?

I.e, If I have an open ssh session and then block port 22, would that terminate my ssh session, block the traffic on the connection but leave the session open, or only block future ssh connection attempts?

Comment: Good question. I suppose current sessions remain active but not sure.